# StrToDouble, NormalizeDouble, removes last zero from double type

Tags: type-conversion, format, double, mql4, normalize

I have this `string str = "1.52220";`

And i want to send an Order with this price.
I need to convert it in Double.

So when i convert it to double using `StrToDouble`, it removes last 0 and return this 1.5222 and `OrderSend` function is not accepting this value, it is return 130 error because amount of digits after decimal points are not normalized.

So then i try: `NormalizeDouble(StrToDouble(str), digits)` but also not working, not added last zero.

I am calculating digits for symbol with this function:

```
int digits = (int)MarketInfo(symbol, MODE_DIGITS);
```

and for this example is 5.

```
double price = NormalizeDouble(StrToDouble(str), digits);
```

Then value of price is 1.5222 and not 1.52220.

Is there some way to don't remove last zero? or the problem is somewhere else?

Or i have to check if last character in string str is zero and than replace it with 1, then would be value fine.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is not with the last zero.

```
  void OnTick()
  {
     int ticket=OrderSend(_Symbol,OP_BUYLIMIT,0.10,1.00,0,0.99,1.01);
     printf("%i %s: ticket=%d, error=%d",__LINE__,__FILE__,ticket,_LastError);
     ExpertRemove();
  }
```

logs (latest first):

```
  2020.05.24 21:14:17.136   2020.05.01 00:00:00  tmpSOF EURUSD,M15: ExpertRemove function called
  2020.05.24 21:14:17.136   2020.05.01 00:00:00  tmpSOF EURUSD,M15: 4 tmpSOF.mq4: ticket=1, error=0
  2020.05.24 21:14:17.135   2020.05.01 00:00:00  tmpSOF EURUSD,M15: open #1 buy limit 0.10 EURUSD at 1.00000 sl: 0.99000 tp: 1.01000 ok
```

Comment: Yes, problem was with order type.